# how can I make limit on cumsum in dataframe and minus to all values

Tags: python, pandas

when I do cumsum with dataframe with lots of datas there's some errors and bugs, so I want to make limit on cumsum data and minus limit value to all datas. Like below

```
A    B    IntA    IntB
1    2       1       2
2    4       3       6
3    6       6      12
4    8      10      20
5    2      15      22
6    4      21      26
7    8      28      34
```

I like to make If minmum value of IntA or IntB goes over 10
minus 10 to before cumsum values and keep doing cumsum like below

```
A    B    IntA    IntB
1    2       1       2
2    4       3       6
3    6       6      12
4    8       0      10
5    2       5      12
6    4       1       6
7    8       8      14
```

Is there any way I could do?

Comment: Can you explain more `If minmum value of IntA or IntB goes over 10 minus 10 to before cumsum values`  ?

Comment: yes right, minus 10 to both before cumsumA, cumsumB values!

Comment: "If minmum value of IntA or IntB goes over 10 minus 10 to before cumsum values" - why do you have greater than 10 values in `IntB` in the expected output?

Comment: Are your As and Bs all in the range 0-9?

Answer (score 0):

Ok finally I think I got it. It would have been easy with `.apply` but it should scale better without and it's also more fun :-)

```
df= pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    'B': [2, 4, 6, 8, 2, 4, 8]
})

cumsumA=  df['A'].cumsum()
cumsumB=  df['B'].cumsum()
tensA=    (cumsumA // 10)*10
tensB=    (cumsumB // 10)*10
tens=     tensA.where(tensA<tensB, tensB)

df['intA']= cumsumA - tens
df['intB']= cumsumB - tens
df
```

This outputs:

```
   A  B  intA  intB
0  1  2     1     2
1  2  4     3     6
2  3  6     6    12
3  4  8     0    10
4  5  2     5    12
5  6  4     1     6
6  7  8     8    14
```

I just didn't recognize immediately, what your `min` rule means for the correction value, but with this knowledge it looks emarrasingly simple...